# Load External JS in custom module

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have tried including external JS in my module, But its fail.

Here is my code, Is there any way to load external JS ??

```
//Loop through the groupings to find grouping file you want to append to

foreach ($js_groupings as $key => $groupings)
{
    foreach  ($groupings as $file => $target)
    {
        //if the target grouping is found
        if ($target == 'include/javascript/sugar_grp7.min.js')
        {
          // I have to load external JS here
$js_groupings[$key]['https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/xyz.js'] = 'include/javascript/sugar_grp7.min.js';
$js_groupings[$key]['custom/JavaScript/sha256.js'] = 'include/javascript/sugar_grp7.min.js';
}
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean with "fail" (error message, expected result). Please provide the information necessary to understand and reproduce your problem, see how to create a [example].

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think you can use Web-URLs/external scripts in JS-Groupings. JS-Groupings are for aggregating many local JavaScript files into a single one in order to speed up loading. You'll have to replace the `https://` file with a local version of the file or remove it and instead link the file in a different way (without JS-Groupings).
- Remove the contents of `/cache/`, then run Quick Repair & Rebuild *twice* and finally *Admin > Repair > Rebuild JS Grouping Files*.
- If the local scripts are not loaded after above steps, completely flush your Browsers Application Cache for the site.

For loading external JavaScript you may want to look at: https://community.sugarcrm.com/community/developer/blog/2016/02/01/using-script-and-css-loading-plug-ins-for-easy-sugar-integrations

There, in highcharts-example.js they load the scripts in the Controller, via the [ScriptLoader-Plugin](https://github.com/sugarcrm/BuildingBlocks/tree/master/packages/ScriptLoader).

In your case this could look something like:

```
({
    //extendsFrom: 'RecordView',

    custom_plugins: [
        'ScriptLoader'
    ],

    custom_scripts: [
        "https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/xyz.js",
    ],

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.plugins = _.union(this.plugins || [], this.custom_plugins);
        this.scripts = _.union(this.scripts || [], this.custom_scripts);
        this._super("initialize", arguments);
    },

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried this, But no luck ;-(
Any other methods?